# Laravel/lumen 5.2 generate migration tables from existing database

Tags: laravel, lumen, laravel-migrations, lumen-5.2

Is possible to generate migration schema from existing database in lumen/laravel 5.2 ? is there any package?

I connect lumen to magento database, now I need to use eloquent. 
I dont have time to make  migration model for every table.

Comment: You don't need to create migrations to use eloquent with existing tables, unless I misunderstood your question

Comment: i really need to generate migratiron

Comment: Then try this, might help you https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator

Comment: Nevermind doesn't work with lumen https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator/issues/65

Answer (score 8):

You can dump database first with [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) tool to the sql file and then in your migration you can do somethink like this:

```
public function up()
{
    $path = 'path_to_sql/dump.sql';
    DB::unprepared(file_get_contents($path));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some easy way I found:

- Install the last version of Laravel and create a project named 'migratedb'
- Set the env database to the one you want to migrate
- Install the Xethron library to create migrations, https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator and follow the instructions
- Install the Iseed library to create reverse migrations, https://github.com/orangehill/iseed and follow the intstructions
- Copy the content from database/migrations and database/seeds from Laravel 'migratedb' to your Lumen project