# How to generate migration from existing tables?

Tags: laravel, migration, generate

**i'm updating a project** to laravel and I want to generate migrations from the existing database.
someone to give a tip, solution link, video?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create migrations from database in Laravel 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63684110/create-migrations-from-database-in-laravel-7)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel/lumen 5.2 generate migration tables from existing database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36887559/laravel-lumen-5-2-generate-migration-tables-from-existing-database)

Comment: see: https://github.com/bennett-treptow/laravel-migration-generator?ref=laravelnews